# Is there a way to read web browser console output?

Tags: browser, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, userscripts

I need to read web browser console output without accessing the source-code. Most user-scripts are based on javascript, Because of that, it doesn't allow to read previous console outputs. I need a find another way to solve this problem.

My next option is to develop web browser extensions. Still, I don't know it's feasible or not.

If it dosen't works my last option is to customize some opensource web browser's code.

If anyone has any idea to access the console output of a web browser, please help me. Maybe this is off topic post in StackOverflow. I have posted this on Software Recommendation section. But It has only one view. That's why I'm posting it here. If this is an off-topic please post your answers in comments.

Comment: The usual method of automating this is Puppetteer or a similar WebDriver-based tool that's built on Remote Debugging Protocol. The relevant event is [Runtime.consoleAPICalled](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Runtime/#event-consoleAPICalled). You can also use it in an extension by attaching to a tab via chrome.debugger API.

Comment: An alternative solution for an extension is to override (hook, spoof) console.* methods in a script with ["run_at":"document_start"](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#run_time), see [Insert code into the page context using a content script](//stackoverflow.com/a/9517879)